# Affilinet WSDL php script -> Output as XML

Tags: php, soap

I have copied the WSDL/php script from Affilinet and would like to create a xml file out of it, so I can import it into Woocommerce.

I have this code so far:

```
<?php

// Set webservice endpoints
define("WSDL_LOGON", "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl");
define("WSDL_WS", "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/PublisherInbox.svc?    wsdl");

// Set credentials
$username = 'xxxxx'; // the publisher ID
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'; // the publisher web services password

// Send a request to the Logon Service to get an authentication token
$soapLogon = new SoapClient(WSDL_LOGON);
$token = $soapLogon->Logon(array(
'Username'  => $username,
'Password'  => $password,
'WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'
));

// Set DisplaySettings parameters
$displaySettings = array(
'CurrentPage' => 1,
'PageSize' => 1000,
'SortBy' => 'LastChangeDate',
'SortOrder' => 'Descending'
 );

// Set SearchVoucherCodesRequestMessage parameters
$params = array(
'StartDate' => strtotime("now"),
'EndDate' => strtotime("now"),
'VoucherCodeContent' => 'Filled',
'VoucherType' => 'AllProducts'
);

// Send a request to the Publisher Inbox Service
$soapRequest = new SoapClient(WSDL_WS);
$response = $soapRequest->SearchVoucherCodes(array(
'CredentialToken' => $token,
'DisplaySettings' => $displaySettings,
'SearchVoucherCodesRequestMessage' => $params
));

// Show response
//print_r($response);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
```

The code like this returns an stdClass Object as an array.

How can I get an xml output from this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.
Karolin

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

Comment: Thanks.

I tried the first example and now the output is html. I need xml or csv.

Comment: What do you mean? that function gives back a XML string, then you just have to save the string in a XML or CSV file.

Comment: Mmh. I added this at the  bottom:

    echo "Response:\n" . $soapRequest->__getLastResponse() . "\n";

and now the output is this: [link](http://46.128.200.107/affilinet-gutscheine.php)

Comment: I can't see your link, please use some other way to share it (i.e. for photos http://imgur.com/ )

Comment: The link is working. Actually I just played around with it. Maybe you got an 500 error. Should work again.

Comment: one solution is to save it to a file with http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php or use http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php to have it as an Object in php and then get the info from that

Comment: I am really not good at this. Thanks. Wil rethink this. Maybe I am just missing out on something here.

Comment: I get something which looks like xml now but I have these nodes (?) now looking like this
    <a:VoucherTypes>
How can I remove the a: so it looks like a normal xml file?

Comment: update your post with the new info/question